# Want to update custom options text in magento 1.7.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento, magento-1.7

[image]

check the custom options. I need to change this.
Onclick on each options the div showing price `([Add $200] or [Substract $50])` should get `display none`.
means when you click on `green` the corresponding price block `must not visible` but red and yellow price block should be visible.

similar when you click on yellow `[substract $50]` must not visible but other price blocks should be visible

Comment: share HTML of option part, because no one will suggest any javascript or jQuery with reviewing html.

Comment: hey rajiv..i already told its magento 1.7.0.2.. so you should know from where custom options html is coming

Comment: its coming from Select.php of app->code->core->mage->catalog->block->product->view->options->type->Select.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below jQuery code to view.phtml. I have tested it with default magento layout.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('ul.options-list li .product-custom-option').click(function(){
            var inputId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
            jQuery('ul.options-list li span.price-notice').css('display','block');              
            jQuery('ul.options-list li').removeClass('active');
            jQuery("#"+inputId).parent().addClass('active');
            jQuery('ul.options-list li.active span span.price-notice').css('display','none');   

        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope will work for you!

Comment: using jQuery you can update custom options price, but it will not reflect to cart price. If want to change some styling, then you can do it.

Comment: On that image product price is $400.When i click on green it will be $500.But when it gets $500 then red should show $100 not $200. How can i achieve this?? Also yellow should show -$150

Comment: can you tell me how can i do this??

Comment: you can updated. But you have create ur own logic behind this. only I can help to find out selected option price and each option price in loop. Here is the code: `var price = jQuery('ul.options-list li.active span span.price-notice span.price').html();
    price = parseFloat(price.substr(1)); // selected option price
    jQuery('ul.options-list li span.price-notice span.price').each(function(){
      var newprice = jQuery(this).html();
      newprice = parseFloat(newprice.substr(1)); // each option price      
    });`